# ImportError when I try to import Detector from py-feat

Tags: import, importerror

I'm very much an amateur when it comes to programming but I'm trying to analyze faces in PyCharm for a psychology research project I'm on. I tried to import the Detector function from py-feat according to tutorials on their website (https://py-feat.org/basic_tutorials/01_basics.html) using both "from feat.detector import Detector" and "from feat import Detector". I've gotten ImportErrors for both, and I've spent a few days trying to fix it to no avail.

The error message I get when I try "from feat.detector import Detector" is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cathe\PycharmProjects\EyebrowProject\venv\Scripts\eyebrow2.py", line 11, in <module>
    from feat.detector import Detector
  File "C:\Users\cathe\PycharmProjects\EyebrowProject\venv\lib\site-packages\feat\detector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from feat.utils import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'openface_2d_landmark_columns' from 'feat.utils' (C:\Users\cathe\PycharmProjects\EyebrowProject\venv\lib\site-packages\feat\utils\__init__.py)
```

The error message I get when I try "from feat import Detector" is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cathe\PycharmProjects\EyebrowProject\venv\Scripts\eyebrow2.py", line 11, in <module>
    from feat import Detector
ImportError: cannot import name 'Detector' from 'feat' (C:\Users\cathe\PycharmProjects\EyebrowProject\venv\lib\site-packages\feat\__init__.py)
```

I've tried just importing feat.detector but got the first error message again. Similarly, I've tried importing feat by itself and got an AttributeError when I tried to run feat.Detector().

I believe I've downloaded all necessary dependencies. I saw online that circular imports might be the issue, but I'm not certain if that's the case here (or how to fix it if it was). Any help would be much appreciated!